# Как хранить данные XML или что?

Tags: php

Есть сайт об играх. На каждой странице есть ссылка на покупку игры в магазине, в котором самая низкая цена.

Раз в сутки скачиваю 5 xml файлов с разных магазинов, некоторые по несколько мегабайт. Для создания страница читаю каждый файл, нахожу в нем игру и цену. Выбираю самую низкую и вставляю в страницу.

И так для каждой странице нужно читать это 5 xml файлов по несколько мегабайт. Страниц много. Посетителей около 2000 в день. Кажется это не совсем эффективно, и затрачивает много ресурсов диска и процессора. Как нужно правильно организовать этот процесс?

Решено! Буду хранить в базе данных.

Как думаете лучше хранить в раздельных таблицах или все сводить в одну? Количество и название полей во всех XML разное.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте базы данных. Напишите сервис который периодически скачивает xml, обрабатывает их и сохраняет записи в БД. А когда пользователь идёт на страницу с игрой отображает данные из БД

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший вариант. Не могу продумать как часто скачивать, когда удалять устаревшие данные, как определять данные которые устарели. Как сделать я представляю, а вот продумать алгоритм работы не могу.

Comment: Например если удалить старые записи, а потом заполнять базу новыми. То пока она заполняется, кто-то из пользователей не получить данные.